# How to import reducers from various files?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, import

I am importing reducers into a single file. How would I reference it properly. It currently keeps reading as 'undefined'.

Here is my directory setup:
redux -> reducer.js
redux -> process.js

process.js contains a single reducer

```
  export  const process = (state = initialState.process, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case PROCESS_PENDING:
        return {...state, 
          pending: true
        };
        return state;
    }
  };
```

reducer.js is the file that I am using to access the process reducer and eventually combine it

```
import process from './process'; 

let test = process;
console.log (test) //undefined

export const allRoot = {
  process,
  values
}
```

I expect the output of the variable test to contain my reducer.
I expect allRoot to contain my process reducer in it.

The actual results are such that process is undefined.

Comment: You only use `import name from './file.js'` when exporting with `export default anyName`.

Comment: the first problem is importing, which is mentioned, and the second, this is not the way of combining reducers, redux itself has `combineReducers` feature

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `import { process } from './process'` or you can use `import * as reducers from './process'` if you'll have many reducers in the future.